# Pset5 implementation of Load using trie

Tags: c, trie, cs50

I'm having some trouble in the pset5, I actually don't know how to start debugging, I've watched the lessons a few times now and I'm not getting anywhere..

When I run speller.c it is giving me a seg fault, I ran the debugger and it crashes at the beginning of the For Loop, here follows my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"
// default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

//created the struct node
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node * paths[27];
}
node;

int letter = 0;
char * word = NULL;

/**
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */ 
bool check(const char *word)
{
//todo
return false;
}

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
//opens dictionary for reading
FILE *fp = fopen(DICTIONARY, "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    return false;
    unload();
}

//creates the root of the trie
node *root = malloc(sizeof(node));
root -> is_word = false;

node * trav = root;

char * word = NULL;

//start reading the file
while (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        //assessing which path to take
        char c = fgetc(fp);
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            letter = tolower (c);
            letter = letter -'a';
        }
        else if (isalpha(c))
        {
            letter = c;
            letter = letter -'a';
        }
        else if (c == '\'')
        {
            letter = 26;
        }
        else if (c == '\0')
        {
            trav -> is_word = true;
        }
        if (trav -> paths[letter] == NULL)
        {
            node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (new_node == NULL)
            {
                return false;
               unload();
            }
            //point to new node
            trav -> paths[letter] = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            trav = trav -> paths[letter];
        }
    }

}
if (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) == EOF)
{
    fclose(fp);
    return true;
}
return false;
}

/**
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */
unsigned int size(void)
{
// TODO
return 0;
}

/**
* Unloads dictionary from memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool unload(void)
{
// TODO
return false;
}
```

I also don't know how to point the new_node to the next new node and if I must have different names for them. For example, I'm going to store the word "foo", so I read the node called trav, go to the path[5] (the f letter), check if it is already opened, if not (if it's NULL) I create a node called new_node and point trav -> paths[5] to it, than I should update trav to be the new node, so I point it to it's own path[letter]?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you do know that `return` returns *immediately*? Any code in the same scope after the `return` will not be executed, it's so called *dead code*. In the `load` function you have such *dead code* if you fail to open the file.

Comment: As for your problem, where does `word` point when you pass it to `fscanf`? The `fscanf` doesn't allocate memory for you.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code pointing word and just forgot to post here:    char * word = NULL;

Comment: Yes, `word` is a null pointer. And `fscanf` doesn't (can't really) allocate memory for that pointer to point to. So what happens when `fscanf` wants to dereference `word` to write the characters it reads? You can't dereference a null pointer, it leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). I suggest you define `word` as an *array* instead.

Comment: Thanks! it worked!! =)

Answer (score -1):

`word` is a `NULL` pointer. And `fscanf` doesn't (can't really) allocate memory for that pointer to point to. So what happens when `fscanf` wants to dereference `word` to write the characters it reads? You can't dereference a `NULL` pointer, it leads to undefined behavior. I suggest you define word as an array instead.

Note : Answer taken from comments